# Can we say that "you need a sleep"?

Tags: grammar

Someone told that to me, I want to know if its correct grammatically. 
Can we quantify sleep? Can we say *a sleep*?
I think we should say "you need to sleep".

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but as a reminder, it is an expectation of Stack Exchange that you demonstrate your initial research efforts. MW: *[sleep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleep), n. 3a: a period spent sleeping; b: night;  c: a day's journey*. The informal use of countable *sleep* as *nap* or *rest* seems unremarkable.

Comment: You can't count *sleep* (*one sleep, two sleeps, three sleeps, four*) but you can certainly quantify it (*some sleep, a little sleep, enough sleep, more*).

Comment: You can count sleeps, according to common British usage, and at least one dictionary.

Comment: If it was spoken, are you sure the statement wasn't: _You **needa** sleep._ as in colloquial _need to_?

Answer (score 2):

Sleep can be a countable noun, meaning 'a period of sleeping'.

> [ C ] (countable)
>
> a period of sleeping:
>
> UK You must be tired after all that driving - why don't you have a
>   little sleep?
>
> He fell into a deep sleep.
>
> You'll feel better after a good night's sleep.
>
> [ C ] (countable)
>
> informal a night's sleep, used especially when saying how far away in time something is:
>
> It's only one more sleep till we go to Disneyland!
>
> How many sleeps until I see you again, Daddy?

[Sleep (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sleep)

Comment: As a lifelong speaker of American English and lifelong listener of all that passes my way, I have never once heard such an utterance as *one more sleep* or *how many sleeps*.

Answer (score 0):

You should say "you need a nap" or "you need some sleep". Sleep is uncountable, you can't quantify it.

> "I just need to get some sleep." source https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleep#examples

If you go on **Skell** https://skell.sketchengine.co.uk/run.cgi/concordance?lpos=&query=features you'll get the word sleep in various examples of sentences, listed according to the number of hits and to their popularity in use. You can observe how, when used as a noun, it is always uncountable.

Nevertheless I have found this sentence:

> "I had a great nights sleep that night."

However it has very few hits, and looks like a seldom used form, almost an archaism, to me, and sleep requires to be paired with "nights" before it.

Comment: In Britain, certainly, we can 'have a sleep'. Macmillan Dictionary says that a catnap is `a short sleep, especially during the day`.

Comment: "Nevertheless I have found this sentence: "I had a great nights sleep that night.." - ." "night's" is the correct form.

Comment: I am sorry for the typo, though  https://skell.sketchengine.co.uk/run.cgi/wordsketch_concordance?headword=sleep-v;gramrel=subject%20of%20%w;coll=night-n

Comment: Algae, you wrote "sleep is uncountable". It is not.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Are you sure this is a UK thing, and not some local dialect where you live?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey OK CD says it's countable, but would you say "I was so busy, I only had five sleeps last week"

Comment: MaxB, I am not a yokel. Countable sleeps are in the Cambridge and Macmillan dictionaries. You probably  would not say 'I had five sleeps last week', but having a sleep involves a count, even if the total is equal to one. An Australian golfer said "I was just knackered on Wednesday so I had two sleeps rather than play any practice holes". You have heard of Google?

Comment: https://genius.com/Kermit-the-frog-one-more-sleep-til-christmas-lyrics